# Datetime in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, cpp-ethereum

how can i get date time in solidity like that: 14/10/2020 20:50. I don't want 8:50 PM.

I get in timestamp but timestamp not possible convert because I have  wrong timestamp.

Comment: i have the timestamp of the wrong conversion in my date time also but i cant do new Date becase Date does not exist (syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timestamp` format in solidity and convert it to and from `datetime` in javascript client side.

For exmaple you can see this page and use these methods to convert `timestamp` to and from `datetime` format:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/